# How to show multiple views (CompositeView) in a region - Backbone Marionette

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I have some CompositeViews, and i want to render it in a region.
CompositeView count is dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

```
Container = Backbone.View.extend() // Not itemview, it needs a template

items = document.createDocumentFragment();
_.each(Data, function(m, k) {
    items.appendChild(new CompositeView({collection: new Collection(m)}).render().el);
})

App.region.show(new Container({el: items}))
```